# Renaming main.rs and using with cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to change the name of `main.rs` and still have commands like `cargo run` work?

If it is possible could someone give me an example of how to have `cargo run` target say `example.rs`?

Comment: I strongly advise you to _not_ do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. There are two ways to create executable targets that don't have `main.rs` at their root.

### Method 1: Declare a binary target in `cargo.toml`

Add an entry to you `cargo.toml` that resembles the following:

```
[[bin]]
name = "example"
path = "src/example.rs"
```

You'll then be able to run your `example` target via

```
$ cargo run --bin example
```

Any number of binary targets can be declared in this way.

### Method 2: The `bin` directory

All Rust files in the `src/bin` directory of your project act as binary targets. If you move `src/example.rs` to `src/bin/example.rs`,  you'll be able to immediately run your `example` binary with

```
$ cargo run --bin example
```

No `cargo.toml` configuration required.

Do note that once you've declare more than one binary target, you will need to use the `--bin` flag whenever you invoke `cargo run`. For more information, see the [Cargo Targets docs for binary targets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries).